# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in eclips

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am using Eclipse and MySQL, but at the time of inserting the values in the respective fields the error appears as " Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Following is the code:

```
package pkg1;

import java.io.IOException;   
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;   

import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;   

@WebServlet("/loginreg")  
public class loginreg extends HttpServlet {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    Connection con = null;  
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;  


    public loginreg() {    

    }    

            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
                try{    
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");     
                    con =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms","root","12sanil1992");



                    System.out.print("\n Insert Values: ");
                    stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?)");

                    stmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("Username"));
                    stmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("user_Password"));


                    Object data = "No of Rows Affected: "+ stmt.executeUpdate();
                    con.close();            

                    request.setAttribute("data", data);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login1.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                    request.setAttribute("data", ex);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login1.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
                finally
                {

                }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using 12sanil1992 as the password, which is probably the wrong one that's why you are getting access denied.

```
  con =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms","root","12sanil1992");
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29)